# Why in C++ 'virtual' and '=0' is both needed to describe a method is abstract?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual, derived-class, pure-virtual

As it is explained in **The C++ programming language**:

```
virtual void push(char c) = 0;
virtual void pop() = 0;
```

The word `virtual` means 'may be redefined later in a class derived from this one'
The `=0` syntax says that some class derived from **Stack** must define the function.

So why `=0` symbol is needed? Does it means that a derived class must define this function, and that's to say when there is no `=0`, some derived classes are not forced to define this method?

I'm confusing about this, need some help.

Comment: in short: Yes. virtual means they **can** be overridden in a child class. =0 makes this function abstract so It **has to** be overridden.

Comment: You don't have to override virtual = 0 functions. If you don't then the class you defined will be abstract as well. If you plan to actually instantiate a class you will have to override the pure virtual functions eventually.

Comment: Well having a class without ever instantiating it seems kind of stange though. (Ok in library develeopment maybe it can be valid)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your thoughts were right.

> So why =0 symbol is needed? Does it means that a child class must
>   define this function, and that's to say when there is no =0, some
>   child classes are not forced to define this method?

Basically you can:

- Make a method non-virtual

This doesn't allow any class deriving from the class that implements the method (through either `public` or `protected`) to change the method's behavior.

- Make a method `virtual`

This allows (but doesn't enforce) any class deriving from the class that implements the method (through either `public` or `protected`) to change the behavior of the method in the base class. You don't even have to call the original base class method anymore so you can make severe changes if needed.

- Make a method `pure virtual` ( `virtual = 0` )

This enforces that any class deriving from the class that implements the method (through either `public` or `protected`) to implement some kind of behavior/body for this method. If the deriving class does not provide an implementation then this class will instantly become abstract itself. This allows to omit the behavior/body of the method in the base class and because of this it is not allowed to directly instantiate a class that has one or more pure virtual methods (abstract class).

Answer (score 5):

> So why =0 symbol is needed?

Consider the following:

```
struct foo
{
    virtual void some() const { cout << "foo" << endl; }
};

struct bar : public foo
{
    virtual void some() const { cout << "bar" << endl; }
};

struct baz : public foo
{
}
```

Suppose you have a pointer `foo *p` pointing to some object, and you call `p->some()`.

- If `p` points to a `bar` object, it will print `"bar"`.
- If `p` points to a `baz` object, it will print `"foo"`.

In some cases, this might not be what you want. You might want to specify that *any* derived class needs to override it. The `=0` does that.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of an *abstract class* (those classes have pure *virtual method*, `=0`) is to provide an appropriate base class from which other classes can inherit. Abstract classes cannot be used to instantiate objects and serves only as an *interface*.

Thus, if a subclass of an abstract class needs to be instantiated, it *has to* implement *each* of the virtual functions, which means *that it supports the interface declared by the abstract class*.

That is the base concept for **interface**.

In short, it a way to be sure a derivative class will implement those methods from the base class.

Answer (score 2):

> So why =0 symbol is needed?

Virtual function with sequence `= 0` is known as *pure virtual function*, (the sequence `= 0` is known as *pure-specifier*), it makes the class an [abstract class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class), which can't be instantiated. For the derived classes, if they want to make it possible to be instantiated, they have to implement the pure virtual function.

> No objects of an abstract class can be created. Abstract types cannot be used as parameter types, as function return types, or as the type of an explicit conversion. Pointers and references to an abstract class can be declared.

For example,

```
class Stack {
    virtual void push(char c) = 0;
};
...
Stack s; // Fail, Stack is an abstract class
```

and if

```
class Stack {
    virtual void push(char c);
};
...
Stack s; // Fine, if you won't call `push()` on it.
```

Answer (score 1):

First consider what is the reason to use virtual methods.

**1.Interface(polymorphism).**

Interface in C++ is a pure virtual class, which means, that all of its methods are pure virtual (like these two you've mentioned above), it has an virtual destructor and has no constructor (it's obvious, because we can't create its instances). It also shouldn't have any data.

Let's define an interface (pure abstract class in C++):

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface(){}
    virtual void somePublicMethod() = 0;
};
```

And define the class, which is an implementation of interface:

```
class Implementation : public Interface
{
public:
   ~Implementation() override {}
   void somePublicMethod() override {}
};
```

If you define another pure virtual method in interface:

```
virtual void anotherPublicMethod() = 0;
```

And you don't override it in implementation you will receive compilation error, when you will declare object of Implementation type, because real Implementation object must have definitions (bodies) for all derived methods.

Yo can also define default behavior of some interface's method:

```
void Interface::somePublicMethod()
{
    //define default behavior here
}
```

And call it in derived class:

```
void Implementation::somePublicMethod()
{
    Interface::somePublicMethod();
}
```

How interface is used in polymorphism you will read in other topics.

**2."Ordinary" Inheritance.**

In "ordinary" inheritance you should use virtual methods instead of pure virtual ones, because you want to have instances of both Base class and Derived class(es). Virtual methods only indicates, that they could be overridden in derived class(es).

**Conclusion**

In general, if you want to have an instance of any class, this class must have all methods defined (so the must have bodies and it's obvious that they mustn't be pure virtual).

Answer (score 0):

The `=0` marker instructs the *compiler* that no member function implementation is provided anywhere, and that derived classes of which objects are to be created *must* implement (i.e., override) it. (Of course, the compiler only checks whether an overriding function is *declared* in the derived class definition; the compiler cannot check whether an actual implementation is present in one of the many other translation units.)

This has two implications.

1. Code trying to instantiate a derived class which does not declare an override for a pure virtual base class function is rejected **at compile time**. If the base class member function declaration was missing the `=0`, the compiler would assume that the base class function definition is provided in another translation unit (vulgo: file) and simply compile the code using a derived class without an override. That the base class function definition is actually lacking would still pop up but **only at link time** which is annoying (imagine you are programming a library and the error only pops up at the customer's site when they try to use it).
2. Even if that base class definition of a "normal" virtual base class member function is never used (for example because only derived types that override it are ever instantiated), it is still required by the linker to be present. (There is not really a material reason for that, except that apparently the programmer meant one to be there). For a *pure* virtual function, no definition needs to be (and none can be) provided.

Apart from these implications on the language level, a pure virtual function indicates intent. It is a feature of the language, like `override`, that increases the expressiveness available to the programmer, with some minor language support.